# Service class's @Transactional not invoked in test context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-test

I am using Spring's `@Transactional` in my DAO's service class. The application has beans configured in XML(s) and via annotations like `@Service`.

My test case configuration looks like below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/spring.xml"}),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Service.class})
})
@ComponentScan(...)
public class TestRunner {
  @Autowired
  private Service service;

  @Test
  public void testSave() {
      service.save(...);
  }
}
```

I have below configured in XML:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txmManager"/>
<!-- bean for hibernate5 transaction manager using sessionfactory -->
```

The service class looks as below:

```
@Service
public class Service {

   @Autowired
   private DAO dao;

   @Transactional
   public Entity save(Entity entity) {
       dao.save(entity);
   }
}
```

Now it all works perfectly during source context run but when I run the test cases, the transaction is never invoked. **Note:** there is no NPE on calling `Service.class`'s method.

I tweaked around and noticed that if I create a bean for `Service.class` in my (test) spring xml file, the test cases work as expected, i.e., the transaction manager is called and the in-memory database is updated.

I expected `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` to create a `MergedContext` and the transaction-manager configuration to be automatically kicked in upon `Service#save` call.

Any thoughts on what am I missing here?

Hibernate - 5.2.6.Final,
Spring - 4.2.0.RELEASE,
Spring-test - 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: Try to scan Service class with component scan on your config (remove  @ContextConfiguration(classes = {Service.class})), and add @Transactional annotation on top your Test class.

Comment: @SeymurAsadov 1. Only scanning didn't work for me - it resulted in NPE. 2. I don't want my test cases to run under a transaction, and I don't see how it would help though.